# changing the field name in a leftjoin

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have a Repo with this query

```
@EntityRepository(Refund)
export class RefundRepository extends Repository<Refund> {
getRefundsByUserId(id: number): Promise<Refund[]> {
return this.createQueryBuilder('refund')
.select([
  'refund.id',
  'refund.userId',
  'refund.amount',
  'refund.createdAt',
  'refund.updatedAt',
])
.leftJoinAndSelect('refund.fkFlightRefund', 'flight')
.leftJoinAndSelect('refund.currency', 'refundCurrency')
.leftJoinAndSelect('refund.status', 'refundStatus')
.where({  userId : id })
.getMany();

}
```

My problem is with the refund.fkFlightRefund , I want to return a field name "flight" but i get "fkFlightRefund",

I also tried using this left join :

```
    .leftJoinAndSelect('refund.fkFlightRefund', 'flights' , 'refund.fkFlightRefund.title = :title',
{ title: 'flight' },)
```

after googling the issue ,

is what i'm trying to do possible ?

any help will do !

Comment: In the following line, the `flight` is a table alias instead of columnName. 
 `.leftJoinAndSelect('refund.fkFlightRefund', 'flight')` > According to docs, "The first argument is the relation you want to load and the second argument is an alias you assign to this relation's table." Use the said alias in the actual `select` query

Comment: @SagarChilukuri I don't quite get what is the actual select query , I tried to add a 'flight' field to the select but it didn't change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a [`.leftJoinAndMapOne()`](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/joining-and-mapping-functionality)

So, your code would end with something like:

```
@EntityRepository(Refund)
export class RefundRepository extends Repository<Refund> {
getRefundsByUserId(id: number): Promise<Refund[]> {
return this.createQueryBuilder('refund')
.select([
  'refund.id',
  'refund.userId',
  'refund.amount',
  'refund.createdAt',
  'refund.updatedAt',
])
.leftJoinAndMapOne('refund.flights','refund.fkFlightRefund', 'flight')
.leftJoinAndSelect('refund.currency', 'refundCurrency')
.leftJoinAndSelect('refund.status', 'refundStatus')
.where({  userId : id })
.getMany();

}
```

There is also an optional 4th parameter to set a condition, in case you need it.

Note that if what you want is to map many items (saying it because the naming, `flightS`), you should use `.leftJoinAndMapMany`, so it maps an array of items.

The `flight` in your code just maps this an alias for other joins in the queries, this is why it wasn't working.

Also, another option would be to rename the relation name from `fkFlightRefund` to `flights`, so the left join already maps it to the name you want, though this may not be possible if you have constraints on the column names.